# Warning: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in * on line 1

Tags: php

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php) to create a login page using MySQL. The code seemed to be working flawlessly when I left my computer 2 days ago. Now I come back to work on it, haven't changed anything, and I'm greeted with this warning:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' (this will
>   throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /filelocation/login.php
>   on line 1

Line 1 in login.php literally says only this:

```
<?php
```

It also seems like this warning is breaking the form. When I hit the "login" button, nothing happens besides being redirected right back to the login page to try again.

Why would this be happening?

edit* As requested here is the fist couple lines of my code. Simply copy-pasted:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: You sure there isn't a space, like `<? php`?  Post the first couple lines of that file.

Comment: Edited original post with first couple lines of code. But yes double checked that there are no spaces.

Comment: *"When I hit the "login" button"* - What button's that?

Comment: btw, you sure that `<` and/or the `?` is/are in fact coming from a standard keyboard and not as one from a unicode character?

Comment: The full code on my page is [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php) under "Step 1" of "Building the login system"
I simply copy-pasted that code 2 days ago. And as stated, everything worked flawlessly 2 days ago.
@Funk Forty Niner - The code for the login button can be seen there (although if you want me to repost it here, I'm more than happy to oblige). Also I considering I copy-pasted from that site, it worked 2 days ago, but no longer works, I can't imagine it's a unicode issue.

Comment: sometimes, copied code from a website contains unicode, but if you say that it worked and stopped working suddenly, then I'm baffled.

Comment: Looks like I found the solution! See answer below. Would still love a reason why filezilla would cause that error. Maybe Filezilla is encoding with unicode or something as @Funk Forty Niner suggested? I'll have to look into filezilla settings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got something that seems to work. When uploading my file with filezilla, I am greeted with this Warning.

I decided to try a different FTP program to upload (NppFTP to be specific) and my problem went away. I still have no idea why this works though! Any body know why that might be an issue?

Comment: I think your FTP program was probably not sending as text but as binary. Now "that" would explain it.

Comment: Not sure if this is the appropriate place to continue this discussion or not...but here goes. When I select "ASCII" in Filezilla I get the error. When I select "Binary" I do NOT get the error. To me this seems counter-intuitive. I would think it's the other way around.

Comment: yeah, that is really odd.

Comment: I had the same problem. Forcing FileZilla to send as binary instead of text solved it. Issue was only for include files with a .inc extension.